# How do you say that morning is yet to come?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What should I say when I mean that morning is yet to come.
Are any of the below correct?

> There is still time *in* morning.
>   There is still time *for* morning.
>   There is still time *to* morning.

Comment: There is still time before/until ...

Comment: *Until*, or use *yet* - e.g. "It's not morning yet."

Comment: Uhmmm... how about _**Morning is yet to come.**_

Comment: @DamkerngT. - I think that's the best answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

> There is still time ***until*** morning comes.
>   There is still time ***before*** morning comes.
>   It's not ***yet*** morning.

In your examples

> There is still time *in (the)* morning.
>   There is still time *for* morning.

indicate it is already morning and talk about when morning will end.

> There is still time *to* morning.

is awkward but could have the same meaning as

> There is still time *until* morning *(arrives)*.

Answer (score 1):

"It's not quite morning," or, "It's not yet morning." Also, "before (the) morning (comes)," is fine or, "before the morning has come," or "pre-dawn", or, "before sunrise," or various other expressions.

By the way, be careful of saying, "in morning," because this sounds like, "in **mourning**," which means you are in the process of grieving (for someone).  You can say "in *the* morning", though:

> We can wash the dishes in the morning.
>
> In the morning, I'll tell her.

It'd debatable when exactly *morning* begins, though.  This varies from place to place and possibly even person to person, but almost anytime after midnight *could* be considered morning, so instead of saying "before morning" you can use "early morning":

> He rose early in the morning, long before the sun was up.
>
> It was early morning by the time they stumbled home from the pub.

Note in the second sentence "early morning" is inexact and could be any time from around 1 am to around sunrise, or possibly even later depending on what your audience considers *early*.